# Aspose.pdf.Heading text went to out of the page - DOM pdf approach

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

I am trying to build list text using the heading objects. While entering the text into heading text, the list text is went to out of the page.

```
        Document pdfDoc = new Document();
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Width = 612.0;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Height = 792.0;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin = new MarginInfo();
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin.Left = 72;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin.Right = 72;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin.Top = 72;
        pdfDoc.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom = 72;

        Page pdfPage = pdfDoc.Pages.Add();
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Width = 612.0;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Height = 792.0;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin = new MarginInfo();
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin.Left = 72;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin.Right = 72;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin.Top = 72;
        pdfPage.PageInfo.Margin.Bottom = 72;

        Heading heading = new Heading(0);

        heading.Text = "(a) Text contends that the trial incorrectly completed the Support Worksheet that accompanied the trial. Calculation of the resulting Calculation of the resulting modified child support amount.";

        pdfPage.Paragraphs.Add(heading);
        string outFile = "D:/Text_Xhtmls/Heading.pdf";
```

Please find the image for your reference- [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Rlp.png)

Comment: It seems to be an issue with Aspose.Pdf library. Please log in support forums at http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.pdf-product-family/20/showforum.aspx

Comment: Thank Razzaq, I have posted the issue in the given link with id "635524" and got the tracking id "PDFNEWNET-38887" from aspose support team. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, We are pleased to share that above reported issue logged as PDFNEWNET-38887 is resolved in latest release of Aspose.Pdf for .NET. Please try using the latest release http://www.aspose.com/downloads/pdf/net/new-releases/aspose.pdf-for-.net-11.8.0/